# JQuery UI and JSON data in Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a `controller` :

```
public function fetchAutocomplete()
    {
        $this->load->model('Auto_model');
        if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
            $result = $this->Auto_model->get_data_auto('table', $_GET['term']);
            if (count($result) > 0) {
                foreach ($result as $row)
                    $arr_result[] = array(
                        'name'         => $row->name,
                        'addr'   => $row->address,
                        'tlp'   => $row->tlp,
                    );
                echo json_encode($arr_result);
            }
        }
    }
```

which resulted:

```
[{"name":"Ahmad Hambali","addr":"Jl. Dewata","tlp":"09811"},
{"name":"Mike","addr":"Address","tlp":"0811"},
{"name":"Mike Jorhs","addr":"Address 2","tlp":"08112"}]
```

the view:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!----->
<label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
                    <?= form_error('name', '<small class="text-danger pl-3">', '</small>'); ?>
                </div>
```

and the `JSscript`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#name").autocomplete({
        source: function(data, call) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?= site_url('Auto/fetchAutocomplete'); ?>",
                method: "get",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term: data.term
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log("response --> ", response);
                    call(response); //callback fn

                }
            })
        }

    });
</script>
```

The following is the result:
[![the list is logged but it does not show][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJQsE.png

Pls advise what needs to be fixed in above code to have autocomplete result is listed in `input` element

Answer (score 0):

I was blinded by the autocomplete rule. Do not change property.

I amended my controller :

```
public function fetchAutocomplete()
    {
        $this->load->model('Auto_model');
        if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
            $result = $this->Auto_model->get_data_auto('table', $_GET['term']);
            if (count($result) > 0) {
                foreach ($result as $row)
                    $arr_result[] = array(
                        'label'         => $row->name,
                        'value'   => $row->address,
                        'desc'   => $row->tlp,
                    );
                echo json_encode($arr_result);
            }
        }
    }
```

and it works! Resolved, thanks!

[image]